# How to run cross validation for logistic regression in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a cross validation (leave one out and k fold) using logistic regression in R, binary outcome.

I have a problem with the cost function. I do not understand the cost function in the R help, and found a more intuitive one here on Stack Overflow, but I don't know how to call it, more specifically, how to pass on the arguments.

```
library(ISLR)
D = Default

mycost <- function(r, pi)
{
  weight1 = 1 #cost for getting 1 wrong
  weight0 = 1 #cost for getting 0 wrong
  c1 = (r==1)&(pi<0.5) #logical vector - true if actual 1 but predict 0
  c0 = (r==0)&(pi>=0.5) #logical vector - true if actual 0 but predict 1
  return(mean(weight1*c1+weight0*c0))
}

glm.fit1 = glm(default~balance + student, data = D, family = binomial)
```

The problem is: if R runs several logistic regressions in the background (for example 3 for K=3), how can I pass on the vectors of predicated probabilities (pi) and the vector of actual values ?

I am confused...

Is there a way to use a for loop and do it manually instead of using cv.glm?

Comment: Have you looked at `cv.glm` from the boot package? It has a `cost` parameter, which is a function of two arguments (observed and fitted). Also see the help file therein.

Comment: You may use the `mlr` framework. You can define your cost function: [custom measure](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/create_measure.html) and you have [resampling](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/resample.html) out of the box.

Comment: Yes, I have looked at the help, and found code which does what I want for a cost function, but how do I transfer the arguments? R will randomly generate splits, I don't know which observations will be in each and which model will run, I can't provide any observations and predictions.